# Less space on Top Anchor of UIImageView on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` on top of screen which has a equal width and height. I'm adding everything programmatically, so I don't have a storyboard. I'm giving width, height, top anchor to `UIImageView` and center it to superviews X anchor. Top anchor has constant value of 10.

My problem is that on iOS 11 and later devices, space between top of superview and `UIImageView` is okay but on iOS 10 and before devices, there are less space. I think there is something to do with superview layout margins.

Summary: What I give as a constant is not important, there is always more space on iOS 11 and later devices.

**How I declare It:**

```
    let logo = UIImageView()
    let logoImage = UIImage(named: "logo")
    logo.image = logoImage
    logo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    logo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(logo)

    logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31).isActive = true
    logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    logo.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
```

**How It should be:**
[image: right one]

**Wrong one:**

[image: wrong one]

Answer (score 0):

When I add top constraint with below practice, problem solved.

```
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: logo,
                   attribute: .top,
                   relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                   toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
                   attribute: .bottom,
                   multiplier: 1,
                   constant: 20)
//topConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint])
```